# Python, How to use line from file as key in dictionary, use next line for value?

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a file like this:

```
   Ben
   0 1 5 2 0 1 0 1
   Tim
   3 2 1 5 4 0 0 1
```

I would like to make a dictionary that looks like this:

```
    {Ben: 0 1 5 2 0 1 0 1, Tim : 3 2 1 5 4 0 0 1}
```

so I was thinking something like:

```
   for line in file:
       dict[line] = line + 1
```

but you can't iterate through a file like that, so how would I go about 
doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be what you want:

```
dict_data = {}
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for key in f:
        dict_data[key.strip()] = next(f).split()

print dict_data
```

Output:

> {'Tim': ['3', '2', '1', '5', '4', '0', '0', '1'], 'Ben': ['0', '1', '5', '2', '0', '1', '0', '1']}

#### Discussion

- The for loop assumes each line is a key, we will read the next line in the body of the loop
- `key.strip()` will turn 'Tim\n' to 'Tim'
- `f.next()` reads and returns the next line -- the line after the key line
- `f.next().split()` therefore splitting that line into a list
- `dict_data[key.strip()] = ...` will do something like: `dict_data['Tim'] = [ ... ]`

#### Update

- Thank to Blckknght for the pointer. I changed `f.next()` to `next(f)`

#### Update 2

If you want to turn the list into a list of integers instead of string, then instead of:

```
        dict_data[key.strip()] = next(f).split()
```

Do this:

```
        dict_data[key.strip()] = [int(i) for i in next(f).split()]
```

Comment: bit explanation would be grate for me as well as OP,  I couldn't understand `dict_data[key.strip()] = f.next().split()` line.

Comment: `key.strip()` removes the whitespace (notably the newline character). `f.next().split()` takes the next line in the file, and splits it into a list of its members.

Comment: Great thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for - simple and efficient.

Comment: That `f.next()` call is very sneaky. It only works because a file is it's own iterator! It may be worth noting that in Python 3 you'll need to use `next(f)`, since the `next` method for iterators is renamed to `__next__`.

Answer (score 1):

```
state = 0
d = {}
for line in file:
    if state == 0:
        key = line.strip()
        state = 1
    elif state == 1:
        d[key] = line.split()
        state = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest approach is to first load the full file with `file.readlines()`, which loads the whole file and returns a list of the lines. Then you can create your dictionary with a comprehension:

```
lines = my_file.readlines()
my_dict = dict(lines[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(lines), 2))
```

For your example file, this will give `my_dict` the contents:

```
{"Ben\n": "0 1 5 2 0 1 0 1\n", "Tim\n": "3 2 1 5 4 0 0 1\n"}
```

An alternative approach would be to use a `while` loop that reads two lines at a time:

```
my_dict = {}
while True:
    name = file.readline().strip()
    if not name: # detect the end of the file, where readline returns ""
        break
    numbers = [int(n) for n in file.readline().split()]
    my_dict[name] = numbers
```

This approach allows you easily do some processing of the lines than the comprehension in the earlier version, such as stripping newlines and splitting the line of numbers into a list of actual `int` objects.

The result for the example file would be:

```
{"Ben": [0, 1, 5, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1], "Tim": [3, 2, 1, 5, 4, 0, 0, 1]}
```